# Passing values into a Higher Order Component with React and Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am currently working with react and formik to make place forms on my page but am running into issues. I currently have a state variable called `inputValue` that I want to use as the holder of when the user types into the form. The issue I am having is getting that into the `handleSubmit` within `withFormik`.

The reason for this is that I want to manipulate the data under certain circumstances. I know I can use `values` from Formik but I do not know how to manipulate that. Is there a way to pass `inputValue` into the HoC that is `withFormik` or is that not possible?

```
class SendMessageContainer extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        inputValue: '',
      };
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
     const {
        placeholder,
        values,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        handleSubmit,
        isSubmitting,
        channelId,
     } = this.props;

     return (
        <Input
           onKeyDown={(e) => {
              if (e.keyCode === ENTER_KEY && !isSubmitting) {
                 handleSubmit(e);
              }
           }}
           onChange={(e) => {
              this.handleChange(e);
           }}
           onBlur={handleBlur}
           name="message"
           value={this.state.inputValue}
           placeholder={`Message #${placeholder}`}
        />
     );
   }
}

export default withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({ message: '' }),
  handleSubmit: async (values, { props, setSubmitting, resetForm }) => 
  {
     if (!values.message || !values.message.trim()) {
        setSubmitting(false);
        return;
     }

     await props.onSubmit(values.message);
     resetForm(false);
  },
})(SendMessageContainer);
```

Comment: You should look into why you're handling form level state in both Formik and your own component - if a value should only conditionally update, I would do that in the actual <Input /> component, that then conditionally calls the Formik handleChange callback, and let Formik handle the form state (which is it's purpose).

Comment: @AndrewBreen the only issue I have is that the value change comes from a click on a different part of the page not onChange in the input. So when that happens, it doesnt trigger it in the Input section